# How to lock text onto an image without it moving around?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to figure out how to lock text onto a specific part of an image, so that if the image moves the text will move with it and stay in the same place relative to the image. this is the code i have so far. The text is only in the correct place relatively to the background on my computer, but when uploaded, the background will move. How do i stop the background from changing size on different webpages? Or how can i make sure that the text stays in the correct place on the image?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.links {
font-smooth:never;
 font-size:11px;
 color:Black;
 font-family: arial;

</style>
<style>
body {
    background-image: 
url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/19bdc0c46a2919225d00518b4239ef85/8b9ee5db2cd2c1f2-3d/s1280x1920/5808f94f9307445928bde5188ff2f16cbb363193.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 480%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
}
</head>
</style>
<body>
<b>
<br />

<p class= links><p style="font-smooth:never;
 font-size:11px;
 color:Black;
 font-family: arial; position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:559px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Thatkiddvee- Stuck_With_You </p>

<p class= links><a href= "https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/thatkiddvee/stuck-with-you" style="position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:552px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Stuck_With_You</a> </p>
   
 <p class= links><a href= "https://youtu.be/Oj7_R31LV1k" style="position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:534px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Stuck_With_You (Music Video)</a> </p>


<p class= links><p style="font-smooth:never;
 font-size:11px;
 color:Black;
 font-family: arial; position:fixed; right:627px; bottom:507px; width:250px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Thatkiddvee- Love_Don't_Cost_A_Thing </p>

<p class= links><a href= "https://youtu.be/qnzU3UhDQb8" style="position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:502px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">inspo.mp4</a> </p>
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping out pixels for percents? Pixels are hard values. Percents will make sure the p tag stays in the same position relative to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your background-size to cover.

```
background-size: cover;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.links {
font-smooth:never;
 font-size:11px;
 color:Black;
 font-family: arial;

</style>
<style>
body {
    background-image: 
url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/19bdc0c46a2919225d00518b4239ef85/8b9ee5db2cd2c1f2-3d/s1280x1920/5808f94f9307445928bde5188ff2f16cbb363193.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
}
</head>
</style>
<body>
<b>
<br />

<p class= links><p style="font-smooth:never;
 font-size:11px;
 color:Black;
 font-family: arial; position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:559px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Thatkiddvee- Stuck_With_You </p>

<p class= links><a href= "https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/thatkiddvee/stuck-with-you" style="position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:552px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Stuck_With_You</a> </p>
   
 <p class= links><a href= "https://youtu.be/Oj7_R31LV1k" style="position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:534px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Stuck_With_You (Music Video)</a> </p>


<p class= links><p style="font-smooth:never;
 font-size:11px;
 color:Black;
 font-family: arial; position:fixed; right:627px; bottom:507px; width:250px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">Thatkiddvee- Love_Don't_Cost_A_Thing </p>

<p class= links><a href= "https://youtu.be/qnzU3UhDQb8" style="position:fixed; right:675px; bottom:502px; width:200px; height:50px; border:none; text-decoration: none"><font color="black">inspo.mp4</a> </p>
    </p></p></b></body></head></html>
```